# Using Tweepy to extractonly the 'text' and 'language' fields, if present in homework

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy

I'm working on my homework for a data science class and I don't understand the error I'm getting when I edit the on_data method. "TypeError: string indices must be integers"

Now that that's working, let's filter our data. 
This part is actually pretty easy. 
Change the on_data method of ListenerParser to extract only the 'text' and 'language' fields, if present.
We also want to be able to retrieve a set number of results, so I have set a max_results parameter 
in the constructor. Use that in your edit of on_data to make the object only retrieve up to 
max_results many results.

This is a listener that will extract the data we are interested in and print to stdout

```
class ListenerParser(StreamListener):

    def __init__(self, max_results): 
        super(ListenerParser, self).__init__()
        self.texts = []
        self.langs = []
        if max_results:
            self.max_results = max_results
        else: 
            self.max_results = float("inf")

    ####This is the code I am responsible for as part of my homework###
    def on_data(self, data):
        if data['text'] and len(self.texts) < max_results:
            self.texts.append(data['text'])
        if data['lang']and len(self.langs) < max_results:
            self.langs.append(data['lang'])

    def on_error(self, status):
        print status
```

Now let's get some data! 
start with 10 results for testing. 
once testing is done, increase to 10,000

```
l = ListenerParser(max_results=10) 

auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

stream = Stream(auth, l)
stream.sample()
```

My new code is :

```
import json
class ListenerParser(StreamListener):

    def __init__(self, max_results): 
        super(ListenerParser, self).__init__()
        self.texts = []
        self.langs = []
        if max_results:
            self.max_results = max_results
        else: 
            self.max_results = float("inf")


    def on_data(self, data):
        jd = json.loads(data)
        if len(self.texts)<self.max_results:
            if jd.has_key('text'):
                self.texts.append(jd['text'].encode('utf-8'))
        if len(self.langs)<self.max_results:
            if jd.has_key('lang'):
                self.langs.append(jd['lang'])


    def on_error(self, status):
        print status


# Now let's get some data! 
# start with 10 results for testing. 
# once testing is done, increase to 10,000
l = ListenerParser(max_results=10) 

auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

stream = Stream(auth, l)
stream.filter()
```

It returned ten "406"s and is still running in the ipython notebook. Why is it still running and is 406 an error or a status code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class ListenerParser(StreamListener):

    def __init__(self, max_results): 
        super(ListenerParser, self).__init__()
        self.texts = []
        self.langs = []
        self.count = 0
        if max_results:
            self.max_results = max_results
        else: 
            self.max_results = float("inf")

    ####This is the code I am responsible for as part of my homework###
    def on_data(self, data):
        data_refined = json.loads(data)
        if self.count<self.max_results:
        if data.has_key['text']:
            self.texts.append(data['text'].encode('utf-8'))
        if data.has_key['lang']:
            self.langs.append(data['lang'])
        self.count+=1

    def on_error(self, status):
        print status
```

I think this should work for you? I haven't tried this code on my machine so fix some minor errors by yourself, if any. Ask for any doubt in the comments, Ready to help you :)

Comment: Why json.loads(status)? Wouldn't it be json.loads(data)?

Comment: Yup, it didn't stop at 10 though, when passed that metric as max_result, it just carries on until the script times out.